# A problem on sequentially compact and countably compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Recently I came across a problem as follows

"I know that sequentially compact implies countably compact. But can anybody tell me please that the converse is true or false."

Comment: If your space is metrizable, the answer is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countably_compact_space).

Answer (score 3):

The converse is false. In fact, even compactness doesn’t imply sequential compactness: see Example $3$ in [this PDF](http://www.math.lsu.edu/~lither/7510fall04/compactness.pdf). (The space in question is the product of $2^\omega=\mathfrak c$ copies of the discrete $2$-point space.)

Answer (score 2):

Even compactness does not imply sequential compactness.  Consider the [Stone–Čech compactification of $\mathbb N$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification#The_Stone.E2.80.93.C4.8Cech_compactification_of_the_natural_numbers), $\beta \mathbb N$.  This space is (by definition) compact, but has no non-trivial (*i.e.*, not eventually constant) convergent sequences, and so any one-to-one sequence does not have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Yep, that was the other one that came to mind right away.

Comment: @Brian: I was actually surprised, nay, shocked!, your answer didn't include it!

Comment: :-) Too busy hunting up a presentation of the other one, since (a) it’s more elementary, and (b) I was feeling lazy enough not to want to write it up!

Answer (score 0):

The topological space $\omega_1 \times [0,1]^{[0,1]}$ is countably compact but neither sequentially compact nor compact. Indeed, $\omega_1$ is countably compact, noncompact and $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ is compact (so countably compact), nonsequentially compact.