# convergent sequences in totally disconnected compact Hausdorff spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

I was wondering if it is true that every infinite totally disconnected compact Hausdorff space $X$ contains a convergent sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge 1}$ with limit point $x\in X$, that is, for any clopen neighborhood $O_x$ of $x$ there is an $N\ge 1$ such that $x_n\in O_x$ for all $n\ge N$.

Thank you very much for your input!

Comment: Well, take the constant sequence $x_n  = x$ for every $n$ ?

Comment: Yes, but what about a non-trivial example like a sequence consisting of different elements?

Comment: Well if your space contains another element $y \neq x$, then take the sequence $x_0 = y$ and $x_n = x$ for every $n > 0$. You have to be clear in your statement: are you looking for some sequence $x_n$ such that $x_n \to x$ and $x_n \neq x$ for every $n$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: See this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/324796).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!